# Creating a model of an unknown plant/control system

Tags: control-engineering, mathematics, feedback-loop

I am getting stuck on the math of control systems. I would like to represent my control system as a differential equation/model. Though many examples use constants which I dont seem to have.

I have a program which throttles the output of a video feed by scaling its quality encoder parameter.

The input is the percentage of allowed bandwith usage. (for example: allowed is 2Mb, used is 1Mb; usagepercentage is 50%). Then I have a proportional controller to calculate the error which then goes into a conditioner which makes sure the input into the plant is between 0 and 100.The output of the plant is the current usagepercentage.

I dont know how to go about and representing this as math. Help is much appreciated.
I have plotted the output of my plant to every possible input, and I find that this gives me an exponential graph.

I have tried watching videos online, but havent found anything representative.

Comment: recommend reading thru a 2nd year or 3rd year university course smth like "introduction control theory"... key topics to start: representing differential operators using Laplace transform (i.e. transforms differential equations to algebra and the reverse), pole/zero representation, block-diagrams, bode plots, block-diagram algebra and analysis of feedback loops, bode method, and finally, system identification ..... typically taught over a semester, assumes knowledge of calculus and ODE's to show the concepts (though once used in practice it's 100% easy algebra)

Comment: oh yeah, and also z-transform for implementation in discrete-time systems (i.e. in the microcontroller code)...

Comment: To the title question, system identification. If there's no model-based understanding of the system being controlled, you can still usually do something by making measurements of the open-loop-response, namely *gain* and *phase*. This can be represented and analyzed, most commonly using a *bode plot*. In most cases, a good-enough approximation can be deduced from that data.

Comment: The measurements are made by injecting test signals into the unknown system block, ideally sine wave, at various frequency. Also the "large-signal" behavior should be explored, meaning DC-offsets, behavior near the limits, etc, since in real life, it's often significant.

Comment: Finally, you can skip the system identification and just do trial-and-error. Especially if the system block being controlled has benign behavior. A "PI" controller has the benefits of both simplicity and that it commonly produces a useful result.

Comment: Oh and if you can't do sine excitation, when assessing the open-loop-response, you can also learn a lot from step-response excitation (and also impulse-response, if you have a measurement tool that lets you do FT's).

Comment: It isn't clear what your plant is.  Keep trimming stuff away until you have a block that has video in, video out, and some sort of a quality command or compression level command input -- that's probably your plant.  Then, if possible, **Edit your question** to separate that plant from your intended controller.